# Is it ok to bind whole service to controller scope?

Tags: angularjs

For instance this service :

```
services.factory('ElementsService', function () {

var currentElement = 'default element';

var service = {
    getCurrentElement: function () {
        return currentElement;
    },
    setCurrentElement: function (elmnt) {
        currentElement = elmnt;
    }
}
return service;
```

I often find useful to do the following from controllers :

```
controllers.controller('ElementsCtrl', function($scope, ElementsService) {

    $scope.elementsService = ElementsService;

});
```

To be able to bind the service variables in the html and stay up to date if the variables get changed by some other controller or service. Like so :

```
<p>The current element is : {{elementsService.getCurrentElement()}}</p>
```

My question is : is this ok or should I avoid doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure the concept is OK and saves having to make a number of different scope variables

Another way you can do it is

```
angular.extend($scope, ElementsService );
```

Then in the view you immediately have access to the same data and methods that are returned from the factory

```
<button ng-click="setCurrentElement(someObj)">test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, which way would you recommand? I'm thinking we could face some naming collisions using angular.extend() on multiple services.

Comment: well if that's the case stay with your approach